# Blank Command window upon running C# in Visual Studio using CTRL + F5

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is a problem in two parts - one before and one after reinstalling Visual Studio 2019.

To set the scene, I am trying to lean programming C# following a course on Udemy, in other words I am a complete beginner.

***Part One:***

Regardless of what program I attempt to run, using CTRL + F5, from Visual Studio (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 - Version 16.5.5) - I just get at black Console window with no text the first three to four times I press CTRL + F5, then it works on the next try. Once it works it continues to work every time, even if I makes changes to the program.

Press CTRL + F5 -> Black Console, I close console;

Press CTRL + F5 -> Black Console, I close console;

Press CTRL + F5 -> Black Console, I close console;

Press CTRL + F5 -> Black Console, I close console;

Press CTRL + F5 -> works.

After that it works every time.

Write a new program, and I have to go through this again.

What is causing this?

***Part Two:***

To this someone suggested uninstalling VS, and reinstalling it.

1. All new projects now are a "Hello World" program and include this line of code Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");  they didn't before
2. Here is an example of a program that took a few tries to get to run (See part one):

   using System;

namespace Exercise4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int demeritPrKm = 5;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter speed limit:");
            var speedLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

```
        {
            int demeritPoints;
            int speedExceedance;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter actual speed:");
            var actualSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            if (actualSpeed <= speedLimit && actualSpeed>0)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Speed within limits");

            }
            else
            {
                demeritPoints = ((actualSpeed - speedLimit) / demeritPrKm);
                speedExceedance = (actualSpeed - speedLimit);
                Console.WriteLine("Speed limit exceeded by " + speedExceedance + "km/h, Demerit points: " + demeritPoints);

                if (demeritPoints > 12)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("***** LICENSE SUSPENDED *****");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("** License OK **");

                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tested the example in `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 - Version 16.5.5`, but could not reproduce the issue. Maybe you can try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8&inRegister=true).

Answer (score 0):

You Don't have the `Console.Readkey()` In your codes

try inserting it in the last line of your codes and try building and running again.

Comment: If you test the OP code, you will find it has nothing to do with `Console.Readkey ()`.